# Magento 2 integration with vue-storefront : When Installing the vue-storefront-api locally, it throws error for npm on Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, pwa, ubuntu

To install vue-storefront, i have followed the steps as per documentation guide
**https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/linux-mac.html#requirements**, but while installing vue-storefront-api backend locally, it throws error as shown in image

[image]

> I have checked `install.log` file and you can also check this log.

```
Cloning into '../vue-storefront-api'...
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /tmp/yarn--1569392153518-0.7983839484530655/node but npm is using /home/user/.nvm/v12.10.0/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> sharp@0.21.3 install /home/user/roc/pwa-project/vue-storefront-api/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached /home/user/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.10.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
make: Entering directory '/home/user/roc/pwa-project/vue-storefront-api/node_modules/sharp/build'
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
In file included from ../src/common.cc:27:0:
../src/common.h:78:16: error: ‘Handle’ is not a member of ‘v8’
   bool HasAttr(v8::Handle<v8::Object> obj, std::string attr);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @BhaktiThakkar not yet

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following link it will help you:

> [Magento 2 Vue Storefront](http://Please%20check%20the%20following%20link%20it%20will%20help%20you:%20%20Magento%202%20Vue%20Storefront)

Comment: It's not link, please add link